# Navigating to next page don't work every time when user != null

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to implement login with email and password using Firebase, and i'm having a hard time navigating to the next page if user != null.

sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't !, the console shows the user is logged in, and if i close the App and open it, it will take me to the intended page,

below is the code.
(Keep in mind i'm super noob!, i'm just tying to learn)
thnx.

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: ()async{

              try {
                UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: _email.text,
                  password: _pass.text,


                );
              } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('No user found for that email.')));
                  print('No user found for that email.');
                } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Wrong password provided for that user.')));
                  print('Wrong password provided for that user.');

                   FirebaseAuth.instance
                      .authStateChanges()
                      .listen((User? user) {
                    if (user == null) {

                      print('User is currently signed out!');
                    } else{
                       
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => Home(),),);
                        
                        print('User is signed in!');

                      }





                    }
                );
                }


              }




            },
            child: const Text('Login'),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.teal,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              shadowColor: Colors.yellow,
              elevation: 5,

            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you put the checking of the user inside the catch statement.

What I would suggest is either to put it inside the try statement or to put it after the try/catch statement.

It would look like this:

```
onPressed: () async {
     try {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: _email.text,
              password: _pass.text,
          );
          // User checking would be here.
     } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          print(e);
     }
}
```

or

```
onPressed: () async {
    try {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
             email: _email.text,
             password: _pass.text,
        );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          print(e);
    }
    // User checking would be here.
}
```

Comment: thnx, this worked